# How to re-sort a barchart into it's initial state after sorting in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YEu0gZOuJWNCV0xP80sN?p=preview) were you can sort the data from largest to lowest value, which is great, but when you uncheck the box it sorts alphabetically like so

```
function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); }
```

I have no idea what to replace this with so that it just return to it's initial state before you checked the box, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an array with the correct order of your `name`s:

```
var sortIndex = data.map(function(d){ return d.name});
```

And then use it for sorting:

```
function(a, b) { 
    return sortIndex.indexOf(a.name) - sortIndex.indexOf(b.name); 
}
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SmpDOk7KYSvrM2ioUoxE?p=preview